# Multiple Buttons in iOS as one

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to group several buttons (`UIButton`) together in iOS as one. If either button is clicked a single function should be called with the button id which will then call the appropriate handler.

how can i do this in iOS? My research shows that `UIView` could be the answer. but how to automate calling the same function on press?

Comment: see my answer with this answer you can add multiple button on a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just tie them all to the same IBAction and it should work fine.  So in your header create the -(IBAction) buttonPushed: and then in IB connect all buttons to that same action.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender {
   UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender; //We know sender will be a UIButton
   switch (btn.tag) {
      case 1: { /* do stuff for first button */ break; }
      case 2: { /* do stuff for second button */ break; }
      case 3: { /* do stuff for third button */ break; }
      //Etc.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple button like this.

```
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 50, 50);
    [btn setTitle:@"Send" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTag:1];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(sendBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];

    UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 50, 50);
    [btn1 setTitle:@"YES" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn1 setTag:2];
    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(sendBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn1];

    -(IBAction)sendBtnPressed:(id)sender
    {    
       int tag = [(UIButton *) sender tag];

       if(tag == 1)
       {
       }
       else if (tag == 2)
       {
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction) buttonClicked:
```

create IBAction in viewcontroll.h file and connect your all buttons with this action.